# Search a value in HTML content with Django ORM that don't consider HTML tags

Tags: python, html, django, search, strip-tags

I have a field in database `description` that system will save HTML code in it.

and I have a search system that works with Q:

```
Post.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=keyword) | Q(description__icontain=keyword))
```

It works fine but the problem refers to it when user searchs for example `'<strong>'` or `'strong'` it will returns the rows that have `'<strong>'` word in them but it shouldn't consider the HTML tags.

So how to search a value in HTML content with Django ORM that don't consider HTML tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a good action:

```
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
rows = Post.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=keyword) | Q(description__icontain=keyword))
if rows:
    for j,i in enumerate(rows):
        if keyword not in strip_tags(i.name) and keyword not in strip_tags(i.description):
            del rows[j]
return render(request,'posts.html',{'rows':rows})
```

1. Fetching data from db with filter.
2. Strip tags the results and then filtering them again.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably add a second field called `stripped_description` and use django's `striptags` filter to strip out html tags, and have django search on that field. It should still find the row you need to recall the actual `description` field containing the HTML code, should you need to display that as a result, but that's the only means I've used to "ignore" html tags.

Comment: I think use `django.utils.html.strip_tags` instead of `striptags` filter.

Comment: I think one of the best action for this problem is filtering the db results. means for example : select in db with django orm and then filter the outputs with other python lib like whoosh.

Answer (score 1):

You can or probably should look into a proper search function using [haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/), my favorite search engine to use with it is whoosh (pip install whoosh) if you are not doing hardcore search functions. You can define your content to be indexed like this:

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.description|strip_tags }}
```

It's fairly easy to setup, and once you have done it, setting up for the next project would be in minutes.