# Django : stripping HTML after a search filter with dynamic parameters

Tags: html, django, search, filter, dynamic

Some of my database entries contains HTML, and I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321398/search-a-value-in-html-content-with-django-orm-that-dont-consider-html-tags) a way exclude HTML from the search so that a user who searches "strong" doesn't get any entry that contains a  tag for example.

The issue here is that my search contains a dynamic variable `wordcontentfilter` that looks into a `Sense ForeignKey` that is "linked" to `Mot` and that I don't know how to write the part of the if code `if query not in strip_tags(i.wordcontentfilter)` properly.

The other conditions `and gramGrp_pos not in strip_tags(i.gramGrp_pos) and gramGrp_gen not in strip_tags(i.gramGrp_gen) and query not in strip_tags(i.slug)` works but I need to filter the dynamic part of the search.

Any help please ?

```
# We build the request. This request searches into 
                wordcontentfilter = 'sense__' + wordcontent + '__' + search_type
                print("wordcontentfilter >>> ", wordcontentfilter)
                filterResult = Mot.objects.filter(
                    Q(**{ wordcontentfilter: query }),
                    Q(gramGrp_pos__icontains = gramGrp_pos),
                    Q(gramGrp_gen__icontains = gramGrp_gen) |
                    Q(slug__icontains = query)
                ).order_by("slug").distinct()
                # We strip HTML from results. If user searched a string which can be found in an HTML tag (ex: <strong>), this search result will be removed
                if filterResult:
                    for j,i in enumerate(filterResult):
                        if query not in strip_tags(i.wordcontentfilter) and gramGrp_pos not in strip_tags(i.gramGrp_pos) and gramGrp_gen not in strip_tags(i.gramGrp_gen) and query not in strip_tags(i.slug):
                            del filterResult[j]
```

I tried to replace `if query not in strip_tags(i.wordcontentfilter)` by almost anything Sense__ related and it didn't work :(